# How to access reactjs component state in jquery callback function

Tags: jquery, reactjs

how to access react component state from jQuery "changeDate" event (of jqueryUI date) callback function.

```
var subheader = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            msg: this.props.msg
        };
    },

    componentDidMount: function () {
        $('#date').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        }).on("changeDate", function (e) {
            console.log(this.state.msg);
        });

    },
    render: function () {
        return (
                    // render HTML here.

        )
    }
});
```

but getting this.state is undefined. Please can any one help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem is not specific for React [but JavaScript in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337878/var-self-this).

You can solve it saving `this` somewhere in upper scope:

```
componentDidMount: function () {
    var self = this;
    $('#date').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    }).on("changeDate", function (e) {
        console.log(self.state.msg);
    });
},
```

If you're using EcmaScript6 you can use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
componentDidMount: function () {
    $('#date').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    }).on("changeDate", e => {
        console.log(this.state.msg);
    });
},
```