# Undefined is not an object while evaluating 'this.list.remove'

Tags: javascript, web, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

Why I can't remove items from the array?

The html view, where I am trying to display all objects of the array:

```html
<tbody data-bind="foreach:list" >
<tr> 
  <td data-bind="text:name" class="span10"></td> 
  <td><a class="icon-pencil" href="#"></a>Edit</td>
   here every time you click at the <a> tag i want to remove an element of the array. but it is not working
  <td><a class="icon-trash" href="#" data-bind="click:$root.removeItem " >
  </a>Delete</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

The script:

```
$(function () {
   var customers=[
      {name:'robert'},
      {name:'miguel'},
      {name:'felipe'},
      {name:'juan'},
      {name:'danilo'},
      {name:'federico'}
     ];

     var viewModel = {

        self:this,

        list: ko.observableArray(customers),

        // it's not removing the item of the array.
        removeItem: function(place) {
            this.list.remove(place);
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on [the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

First problem is with the `self:this` thing inside the object literal.

Inside an object literal, `this` will *not* refer to that object. In your code it will refer to the `document`, because the nearest scope is the `$(function() { ... });` setup, which is equivalent to (see [docs](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)) `$(document).ready(...)` where `this` is (somewhat more obviously) bound to `document`.

Here's an example to demonstrate this, A, B, and C all log the same thing (which is *not* the `viewModel`):

```js
console.log(this.document); // A

$(function() {
  var customers = [{
    name: 'robert'
  }];
  
  console.log(this); // B

  var viewModel = {
    self: this
  };
  
  console.log(viewModel.self); // C
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note also that `this` inside your `removeItem` function will refer to *its* closest function scope by default, which is the `removeItem` function itself (and not `window`, `document`, or `viewModel`).

**Solution 1**: if you really want to use object literals, you could first declare the object and add its properties later, e.g.:

```
var viewModel = {};
viewModel.list = ko.observableArray(customers);
viewModel.removeItem = function(place) {
  viewModel.list.remove(place);
};
```

**Solution 2**: if you want to use [the `self = this` idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/337878/419956) I recommend using a constructor function instead:

```
function ViewModelConstructor(myCustomers) {
  var self = this;
  self.list = ko.observableArray(myCustomers);
  self.removeItem = function(place) {
      self.list.remove(place);
  };
}

// Get an instance:
var viewModel = new ViewModelConstructor(customers);
```

---

To put that last suggestion into a fully runnable example:

```js
var customers=[
  {name:'robert'},
  {name:'miguel'},
  {name:'felipe'},
  {name:'juan'}
];

function ViewModelConstructor(myCustomers) {
  var self = this;
  self.list = ko.observableArray(myCustomers);
  self.removeItem = function(place) {
      self.list.remove(place);
  };
}

// Get an instance:
var viewModel = new ViewModelConstructor(customers);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: list">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
      <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeItem">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you put like following

```
self:this,
self.list :  ko.observableArray(customers),
```

I think you have not put self

Comment: That would be a syntax error. `self.list` wouldn't work as an object's key like that.

Comment: actually he didn't put his array in observable and trying to remove something so it wouldn't work tht i think