# click event on button is disabling the default behavior of html required

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

```html
<input name="color" type="radio" data-bind="style: { backgroundImage : 'url('+$parents[1].generateSwatchImage($data)+')'}, checked: $parent.selectedOption, checkedValue: $data ,click : $parents[1].onSelectSwatchAddSlick" required />

<select name="size" required aria-required="true" id = "CC-prodDetails-sku-alphaProduct_size" data-bind="validatableTarget: selectedOption, validationOptions: {decorateElement: false, decorateElementOnModified:  false}, options: optionValues, optionsText: 'key',
                                optionsCaption: $data.optionCaption, value: $data.selectedOption, disable: $parent.disableOptions() || $data.disable, optionsAfterRender: function(option, item) { ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, {disable: !item}, item); },onRender : $parent.AlphaSelector(), event : {change : $parents[1].onSelectDropdownOptionAddSlick}">
                        </select>
```

```js
handleAddToCart: function() {
        notifier.clearError(this.WIDGET_ID);
        var variantOptions = this.variantOptionsArray();
        notifier.clearSuccess(this.WIDGET_ID);
        //get the selected options, if all the options are selected.
        var selectedOptions = this.getSelectedSkuOptions(variantOptions);

        var selectedOptionsObj = { 'selectedOptions': selectedOptions };
        
        //adding availabilityDate for product object to show in the edit summary 
        //dropdown for backorder and preorder
        var availabilityDateObj = { 'availabilityDate': this.availabilityDate()};
        var stockStateObj = { 'stockState': this.stockState()};
        

        var newProduct = $.extend(true, {}, this.product().product, selectedOptionsObj, 
                                        availabilityDateObj, stockStateObj);
        
        if(this.selectedSku() && ! this.selectedSku().primaryThumbImageURL){
          this.assignSkuIMage(newProduct, this.selectedSku());
        }
        if (this.variantOptionsArray().length > 0) {
          //assign only the selected sku as child skus
          newProduct.childSKUs = [this.selectedSku()];
        }
        
        newProduct.orderQuantity = parseInt(this.itemQuantity(), 10);
        var itemQuantityInCart = this.itemQuantityInCart(newProduct);
        var stockAvailable = newProduct.orderLimit&&newProduct.orderLimit<this.stockAvailable()?newProduct.orderLimit:this.stockAvailable();
        if ((itemQuantityInCart + parseInt(this.itemQuantity(), 10)) > stockAvailable) {
          var notificationMsg = CCi18n.t('ns.productdetails:resources.totalItemQuantityExceeded', {stockAvailable: stockAvailable, itemQuantityInCart: itemQuantityInCart});
          notifier.sendError(this.WIDGET_ID, notificationMsg, true);
          return;
        }

        $.Topic(pubsub.topicNames.CART_ADD).publishWith(
          newProduct,[{message:"success"}]);

        // To disable Add to cart button for three seconds when it is clicked and enabling again
        this.isAddToCartClicked(true);
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(enableAddToCartButton, 3000);

        function enableAddToCartButton() {
          self.isAddToCartClicked(false);
        };

        if (self.isInDialog()){
          $(".modal").modal("hide");
        }
      },
```

I am using required in html tags like input and select but the issue is default popover validation of required seems not to be working 
if i use the click on event on button and if i remove that event the require starts working as expected

could someone help ??

```html
 <div  id="CC-prodDetails-addToCart" data-bind="inTabFlow:(validateAddToCart())" >
                <button type = "submit" class="btn primary full-width cart" data-bind="click: handleAddToCart" >
                
                </button>
            </div>
```

Comment: Could you please eloborate more specifically what you are trying to do/achieve? What code do you already have and what are you trying to do that is not working?

Comment: i just wanted to make my required worked but because of my click event its not working i.e if i remove the click event the require seems to be working properly

Comment: Please add the code regarding your "click" event here.

Comment: above i have added the function code which i have used on click event

Comment: i think beacuse of am using the knockout click binding is affecting the html required

Comment: tysm i think i have solved the issue 
i have added a data-bind submit on form tag and called the function there so the functionality and html required behavior both are working fine

------------------------------------

<form id="PDP_Form" data-bind = "submit : $data.handleAddToCart">

Comment: Try returning true from your handleAddToCart so that the click handler doesn't think it should stop execution of the event bubbling.  Optionally move all your required logic to knockout-validation and handle all your validation in knockout.

Answer (score 1):

`return true` on the basic click event is the key

```js
jsClick = function () {
  console.log('jsClicked');
  return true;
};

function MyViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.koClick = function () {
    console.log('koClicked');
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button onClick="jsClick()" data-bind="click: koClick">click</button>
```

Comment: thanks @Sam, but i have already solved the issue and added the comment above

Comment: No @RAVIsingh you are mistaken, you provided a workaround to your problem, I provided an answer to why both events were not firing.

Comment: i got it @Sam,
i just wanted to know one thing actually am bit new to knockout can you please explain me why we use `var self = this` and  instead of `this` coz while i was debugging with printing it with console the data (this and self) was same ,
i wasn't able to understand even after google it.

Comment: please consider marking my response as the answer then, as for your follow-up question; this has been answered numerous times before e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337878/var-self-this or https://scotch.io/@alZami/understanding-this-in-javascript or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback/20279485#20279485

Answer (score 0):

i think i have solved the issue i have added a data-bind submit on form tag and called the function there so the functionality and html required behavior both are working fine  `<form id="PDP_Form" data-bind = "submit : $data.handleAddToCart">`

**Why not just put a click handler on the submit button?**

## Heading

Instead of using submit on the form, you could use click on the submit button. However, submit has the advantage that it also captures alternative ways to submit the form, such as pressing the enter key while typing into a text box.

**

### Parameters

**

- Main parameter

The function you want to bind to the element’s submit event.

You can reference any JavaScript function - it doesn’t have to be a function on your view model. You can reference a function on any object by writing submit: someObject.someFunction.

Functions on your view model are slightly special because you can reference them by name, i.e., you can write submit: doSomething and don’t have to write submit: viewModel.doSomething (though technically that’s also valid).

- Additional parameters

None
Notes
For information about how to pass additional parameters to your submit handler function, or how to control the this handle when invoking functions that aren’t on your view model, see the notes relating to the click binding. All the notes on that page apply to submit handlers too.